# Capture dom element after render DOM - Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, css, mongodb, meteor

I have a student class, inside of them I have two methods one for Meteor event and other one for Meteor Helpers like this :

```js
    /* HELPERS */


    _helpers() {
        Template.students.helpers({
            all_students: () => {
                return students.find();
            },
            styles_html: 'test'
        });
    }


    /* END HELPERS */
    
        /* EVENTS */

    _events() {
        Template.students.events({
            'submit form': (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                let studentsVal = e.target[0].value;
                students.insert({
                    name: studentsVal
                })
            }
        })
    }

    /* END EVENTS */
```

And I call them in my constructor like this :

```js
    /* CONSTRUCTOR */

    constructor() {
        this._collection();
        this._events();
        this._helpers();
    }

    /* END CONSTRUCTOR */
```

And collection method is for create my collection in mongoDB

And I would like to use my private Method call `_grabDom` like this :

```js
    _grabDom() {

        this._dom = {
            list: document.querySelectorAll('.list')
        }
    }
```

Helpers generate the query Mongo on my HTML he create `li` with class list.

But when I trigger `this._dom.list` return empty

I try the `onRendered` method same result.

Thanks

**EDIT**

```html
<template name="students">
    <form action="#">
        <input type="text" class="students {{styles_html}}" placeholder="students">
        <input type="submit" value="go">
    </form>
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            {{#each all_students}}

                <li class="list" data-name='{{name}}'>{{ name }}<span class="deleted">X</span></li>

            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: You should share how you instantiate your class (i.e. when `constructor` is used) and how you call `this._dom.list`. Ideally also share your template HTML.

Comment: I edited with HTML template :) 
And I instantiate my class under of my class like this : new Students()

Comment: "when I trigger this._dom.list return empty" means that when you trigger it the list of all_students has not been rendered yet (probably it is being called before the subscription returns with `students.find()` and that has been rendered to the view).

Comment: Is the subscription ready when your `_grabDom()` runs?

Comment: What's subscription ? I Don't understand

Comment: The data in your collection has probably not been downloaded to the client yet when you render. Then it appears later. You're probably still using `autopublish` which is publishing all data automatically. Eventually you'll remove this package for security/performance reasons and implement publications and subscriptions. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30347841/2805154

Comment: Why are you putting your `Template` code in a class anyway?